# How do i change the url name with routing or url rewrite?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, routes, url-routing

This is my original website when user browse it
http://test/Template/PreviewWebPage/7 
where the 7 is the id that passed into the database and get the data and display the webpage

I would like to ask how can I change the 7 into another name such as 
http://test/Template/PreviewWebPage/Hello where the word Hello still act as an id which will get the data from database.

The Hello word is also can be set by the user and change it such as Food or any other word which the user input

I am using asp.net mvc.

Here are my code for the PreviewWebPage

```
  public ActionResult PreviewWebPage(ShowSectionViewModel model, int id)
    {
        var item = dc.SECTION.Where(x => x.TEMPLATEID == id).OrderBy(x=>x.ORDERINDEX).ToList();
        var item2 = dc.SLIDESHOW.ToList();

        List<slideShowClass> slideShowClassList = new List<slideShowClass>();
        List<sectionClass> sectionClassList = new List<sectionClass>();
        sectionClass sc = new sectionClass();
        slideShowClass ssc = new slideShowClass();
        for (int i=0; i < item.Count(); i++){
            if (item[i].SECTIONTYPE != "Slide Show")
            {

                sc.SECTIONID = item[i].SECTIONID;
                sc.SECTIONIMAGE = item[i].SECTIONIMAGE;
                sc.SECTIONNAME = item[i].SECTIONNAME;
                sc.SECTIONTEXT = item[i].SECTIONTEXT;
                sectionClassList.Add(sc);
            }
            else
            {   
                for (int j = 0; j < item2.Count(); j++) {
                    if (item[i].SECTIONID == item2[j].SECTIONID)
                    {
                        ssc.SECTIONID = item[i].SECTIONID;
                        ssc.IMAGEFILE = item2[j].IMAGEFILE;
                        slideShowClassList.Add(ssc);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        return View(new ShowSectionViewModel()
        {
            TemplateId = id,
            Sections = item,
            SlideShow = item2,
            sc = sectionClassList,
            ssc=slideShowClassList,

        });

    }
```

Sorry for my messy question as this is the first time I ask question at stakoverflow

Here are my code for the route config

routes.MapRoute(
               name: "PreviewWebPage",
               url: "Template/PreviewWebPage/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Template", action = "PreviewWebPage", id =""}
           );

Comment: Have you read up on many articles around about `RouteConfig` class that are available on the web? e.g. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624181/Routing-Basics-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: You may also want to clarify if you are using asp.net mvc or asp.net webforms.

Comment: Please share minimum code example

Comment: What happens currently when you browse `http://test/Template/PreviewWebPage/Hello` ?

Comment: show the same content as  http://test/Template/PreviewWebPage/7. I just wanted to change the word 7 where it could be any id number to word where user will be given a form to type the name on it

Answer (score 0):

before start rewriting url you need to set up your work environnement :
the a2enmod rewrite could perhaps be usefull in your case : 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04.
(That's for linux on which system are you ?)

Comment: i am using windows system and visual studio 2017 to develop this project